# Firebase Auth User Management Programatically from C#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-authenticator, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to manage users on Firebase Auth from my code. I was following the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/manage-users

This is the code I made:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> DeleteAsync(string email)
        {

            try {               

                GoogleCredential cred = GoogleCredential.FromFile("path\\to\\downloadfile\\Mysandboxproject.json");

                FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
                {
                    Credential = cred,
                    ServiceAccountId = "mailserviceaccount@sandboxproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
                });


                //Get User To Remove:
                UserRecord userRecord = await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.GetUserByEmailAsync(email);

                await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.DeleteUserAsync(userRecord.Uid);
                
                return 1;                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

But when it goes to the line where it goes to GetUserByEmailAsync it never returns... doesn't throw exception, nor returns the user, of course the user is never deleted.
What am I doing wrong? am I missing something related with the conection or configuration of firebase comunication? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the Service Account in the same project as Firebase? Does it have the correct permissions? How difficult would it be for you to try the functionality from another language to determine whether it's your configuration or the underlying API method?

Comment: Aside: I encourage you to consider using [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/install-admin-sdk#c_1). It will make your code and its deployment simpler. Don't forget to `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/your/key.json`.

Comment: I just tried the equivalent Golang code on a project that includes Firebase Auth. The project has a service account with Firebase Auth Admin role (roles/firebaseauth.admin). It worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to repro your issue; the following works for me:

```sh
PROJECT=[[YOUR-PROJECT]] # Containing Firebase Auth
ACCOUNT=[[YOUR-ACCOUNT]] # Service Account name

EMAIL="${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud iam service-accounts key create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL}

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=roles/firebaseauth.admin

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json
```

With C#:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using FirebaseAdmin;
using FirebaseAdmin.Auth;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;

namespace app
{
  class Program
  {
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
       FirebaseApp.Create();
            
       var email = "[[EMAIL ADDRESS]]";
       var record = await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.GetUserByEmailAsync(email);
       Console.WriteLine($"Successfully fetched user data: {record.Uid}");
    }
  }
}
```

Then:

```sh
dotnet new console
dotnet add package FirebaseAdmin --version 2.2.0
dotnet run
```

Comment: Thanks DazWilkin, I'm not sure I understand it, where do you run or set the first code fragment. The gcloud code.

Comment: That's to establish the Google (Cloud) Project and the Service Account necessary to run the code. It's documented in the link you included too: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/install-admin-sdk